# Why is clear an O(n) operation for linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, garbage-collection, time-complexity

According to attachment 1, linked list's clear operation is O(n).

I have  a question about why is it so.

Here is how we implemented the linked list in class(java)

```
public class LinkedIntList {
           private ListNode front;
            ......
}
```

And if I were to write a clear method for this linked list class, this is how I would write it

```
public void clear() { 
        front = null;
}
```

Given this implementation(think this is how most people would write this), this would be one operation that is independent of the size of the list (just setting front to null). Also by setting the front pointer as null, wouldn't you essentially be asking the garbage collector to "reclaim the underlying memory and reuses it for future object allocation." In this case , the underlying memory would be the front node and all the nodes that are consecutively attached to it.(http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx)

After stating all of that, **how is clear an O(n) operation for linked list?**

---

Attachment 1:

This is from a data structures class I am in 
[image]

Comment: This falls under "a software algorithm" from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, in this case, a software algorithm to clear a linked list

Comment: @amit - The issue is *unless* all `next` and `prev` references are explicitly set to `null`, leaked references will still keep instances alive. For example, if I have assigned list item at position 1 to a reference (leaked.), then setting `list=null` will just make the first object ready for GC. All other instances will still be *reachable*.

Comment: @TheLostMind `front` is private, and you should assume that in a proper Linked List implementation, you can never have access to the actual `ListNode` object from outside the DS, only for the data. If you try hard you will always get a leakage, but a proper implementation should not allow it anyway, thus setting all pointers to `null` is realy redundant (and overkill) assuming a proper implementation.

Comment: @amit - `front` might indeed be private but I have a *public getter* which gives me *reference* to any node. What if in my program, I access node `1`?. If I don't set `the next` and `prev` references of the nodes following node 1 to null, then they will *still be reachable*. You cannot return *defensive copies of nodes*. So, the implementation has to make sure *everything is cleared*.

Comment: @amit What about an iterator that is still _outside_?

Comment: @TheLostMind If you have a getter that gives the actual `ListNode` element - you have a bad code. I would have implemented `ListNode` as a package protected or private (static) inner class, there is really no need for anyone outside the DS to have any knowledge of it, it should be encapsulated.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose `LinkedList` (in the question) is not implementing `Iterable`, if you do want to implement it, there are tradeoffs to be concerned, and often changing object while iterating it results in Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that a Linked List has `n` entries that were allocated for it, and for clearing it, you actually need to free them.

Since java has a built in [garbage collector (GC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) - you don't need to explicitly free those - but the GC will go over each and every one of them and free them when time comes

So even though your explicit method is `O(1)`, invoking it requires `O(n)` time from the GC, which will make your program `O(n)`

Comment: But doesn't Big Oh disregard stuff like that - processor speed, what operating system you're on?

Comment: @committedandroider Point is that the elements shall have to be cleared. Whether the processor does it for you automatically or you do it yourself is immaterial.

Comment: so Big Oh considers all the auxiliary operations to do a task, even when you don't necessary code it?

Comment: @committedandroider of course,it conciders everything that has to be done to run the code

Comment: to my knowledge, GC works by marking all the objects reachable from roots. All reachable objects are moved to some other area and everything else is declared free. So if front is set to null and assuming there are no other references like in this case, it cannot be reached anymore, so collector need not mark the remaining objects in the list. So how is it O(n) ? :)

Comment: @Arkantos if that was the case, wouldn't the "all reachable objects are moved to some other area" part be an O(n) operation?

Comment: @Arkantos it needs to somehow mark each memoey of each node in the heap memory internal ds as available to allocation

Comment: ya that moving objects part is linear. But it doesn't just depend on the number of elements in your linked list, it depends on the number of all reachable objects created by all the other threads. If you have 10 elements in your list and 100 live objects in that region at the time of GC, and say each move takes 5ns, the whole clearing will take 500ns. Linking that to your code and saying it takes O(n) is not a reasonable argument :)

Comment: Arkantos is right, GC time depends on the number of LIVE objects, the number of dead objects has no effect.    Hence this answer is WRONG.

Comment: @IanRingrose Marking the objects may be constant time in this case. But wouldn't actually **collecting** them (once they are determined to be unreachable) be linear? After all, there will be n objects that the GC has to free/recyle.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, No GC does NOT collect dead objects, it collects LIVE objects.     So the time for GC to run is only depended on the number of  LIVE objects.      A GC does not determines an object to be unreachable, it determines the objects that are reachable, and then keeps these.

The number of times a GC runs could be depending on the number of object allocated.

Answer (score 1):

**I expect that your data structure class is not assuming that JAVA is the only system in the world.**

In C, C++, Pascal, Assembly, Machine Code, Objective C, VB 6, etc, it takes a fixed time to free each block of memory, as they do not have a garbage collector.   Until very recently most programs where wrote without the benefits of a garbage collector.

So in any of the above, all the node will need to be pass to free(), and the call to free() takes about a fixed time.

---

In Java, the link listed would take O(1) time to clear for a simple implantation of a linked list.

However as it may be possible that nodes would be pointed to from outside of the list, or that a garbage collector will consider different part of the memory at different time, there can be real life benefits from setting all the “next” and “prev” pointers to null.    But **in 99% of cases**, it is best just to set the “front” pointer in the header to null as your code shows.

---

**I think you should ask your lecture about this, as I expect lots of the students in the class will have the same issue.**     You need to learn C well before you can understand most generally data structure books or classes.

Comment: I confirm that this is best from a sofware engineers view point, yet probably not from the viewpoint of the algorithm optimizer: The current code for `java.util.LinkedList` does explicitly clear all list nodes making it to true `O(n)`. The comments in method `clear()` point out that explicitly clearing each list node helps the garbage collector.