# Wouldn't remove for a non dynamic unsorted array list be O(n)?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist, time-complexity

This falls under "a software algorithm" from stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, in this case, a software algorithm to remove an item from an unsorted array list

This is from my class when we discussed big oh runtime for different data structures
[image]

My question is about remove value for unsorted non dynamic array. Shouldn't this be O(n) based on how we implemented it(see below)

```
 public void remove(E value) {
    int index = getIndex(value);
    elementData[index] = elementData[size - 1];
    elementData[size - 1] = null;
    size--;
}
public int getIndex(E value) {
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       if (elementData[i].equals(value)) {
           return i;
       }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

While I would agree with the fact that this code segment

```
elementData[index] = elementData[size - 1];
    elementData[size - 1] = null;
    size--;
```

would run in O(1). What I learned from my other question [Why is clear an O(n) operation for linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359942/why-is-clear-an-on-operation-for-linked-list) was that Big Oh "conciders everything that has to be done to run the code", which in this case includes the getIndex function which is bound by O(n). 
Because the remove method consists of O(n) and O(1), it will run in O(n) time.
Does everyone agree with my assessment or did I miss something?

Comment: Your complexity analysis is correct.  My best guess is that the table you are quoting referred to removal of an element given by index, not by value, so the call to `getIndex` would be redundant.

Comment: no the table has remove value and remove by index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. Your `getIndex` function runs in O(n) (O(1/2 * n) on average, but we generally aren't interested in constants).  The other code in your `remove` function runs in constant time, so the total runtime is O(n + c), where c is a constant, meaning the total run time is O(n).

Comment: average because the element usually falls in the middle of the list?

Comment: Yes, because on average the element will be found in the center (given a random array).

Comment: yeah I've always been confused about the the one half because i felt like that was saying the element had to be right in the center, when it could be towards the front or towards the back.

Comment: In a random array, the change for an element to occur in the first half is 50% and the change for it to occur in the second half is 50%. It is the same idea as taking 1,000,000 random numbers between 0 and 1. Adding them all up will always end up around 500,000 because the average value for a random number between 0 and 1, is 0.5.

Comment: Yeah what you just said makes sense. I just don't get how the average case is bounded by O( n * (1/2)). There is a C such that for n >= n0, A(t) <= C * n * (1/2) where A(t) is average case runtime?

Comment: On average it will take n/2 iterations to find the right index. No Big-O. You are correct to say that O(n*1/2) is meaningless because O(n*1/2) equals O(n). Those two Big-O functions are exactly the same thing.